# Is there a way to "debug" the score on Azure Search?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am using a custom scoring profile and would like to know what made one document score higher than others for debugging purposes. Is there a special field I can include on the `$select` or a parameter to pass in to the request? This would help me play around with boosting and weights given my data source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way today in Azure Search to get any sort of explanation for how documents are scored, regardless of whether or not the scoring profile is the default one or a custom option.  [You can vote for that feature here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/7379515-support-explain-api) if you think it would be useful.  For now, I would just do your best to review [our documentation on scoring profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index) and continue to tweak your scoring profile until you see the results you expect to.